# '../Pods-Environment.h' file not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

Found the cause, answer below.

---

I just cloned a remote git repository. It has a workspace with 2 projects. The main and the Pods.

When I try to run my main project, I got an error

"Lexical or preprocessor Issue: '../Pods-Environment.h' file not found.

The UI7Kit is importing this file,

```
//
//  UI7Kit.h
//  UI7Kit
//
//  Created by Jeong YunWon on 13. 6. 11..
//  Copyright (c) 2013 youknowone.org. All rights reserved.
//

/*!
 *      #import <UI7Kit/UI7Kit.h>
 *      [UI7Kit pssatchIfNeeded]; // in main.m, before UIApplicationMain()
 */


#ifdef    COCOAPODS
#include    "../Pods-environment.h"
#else // no cocoapods, so enable everything
```

I tried to resynch, but nothing is different, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like `COCOAPODS` is defined when it shouldn't be...

Comment: Try running `pod install` or `pod update` against it. It has fixed problems like this for me in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some fails I found what was going on.

My project used to have a different UI7Kit.h file. It wasn't even importing the "../Pods-environment.h". -The file that caused the error.

Every time I ran the pod install, I was overwriting the modified file.

If anyone needs the updated file, it looks like this:

```
//
//  UI7Kit.h
//  UI7Kit
//
//  Created by Jeong YunWon on 13. 6. 11..
//  Copyright (c) 2013 youknowone.org. All rights reserved.
//

/*!
 *      #import <UI7Kit/UI7Kit.h>
 *      [UI7Kit patchIfNeeded]; // in main.m, before UIApplicationMain()
 */


#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7Button.h>)
#define UI7KIT_HAS_QUARTZCORE
#endif
#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7PickerView.h>)
#define UI7KIT_HAS_QUARTZCORE
#endif
#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7SearchBar.h>)
#define UI7KIT_HAS_QUARTZCORE
#endif
#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7SegmentedControl.h>)
#define UI7KIT_HAS_QUARTZCORE
#endif
#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7Stepper.h>)
#define UI7KIT_HAS_QUARTZCORE
#endif
#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7TextField.h>)
#define UI7KIT_HAS_QUARTZCORE
#endif

#ifdef UI7KIT_HAS_QUARTZCORE
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#endif

// Core
#import <UI7Kit/UI7KitCore.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7Utilities.h>

#ifdef COCOAPODS

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7Font.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7Font.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7AlertView.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7AlertView.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7ActionSheet.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7ActionSheet.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7BarButtonItem.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7BarButtonItem.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7Button.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7Button.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7NavigationBar.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7NavigationBar.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7NavigationController.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7NavigationController.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7ProgressView.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7ProgressView.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7PickerView.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7PickerView.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7SearchBar.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7SearchBar.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7SegmentedControl.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7SegmentedControl.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7Slider.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7Slider.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7Stepper.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7Stepper.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7TabBar.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7TabBar.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7TabBarItem.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7TabBarItem.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7TabBarController.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7TabBarController.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7TableView.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7TableView.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7TextField.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7TextField.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7Toolbar.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7Toolbar.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7View.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7View.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UI7Kit/UI7ViewController.h>)
#import <UI7Kit/UI7ViewController.h>
#endif

#if __has_include(<UIKitExtension/UIKitExtension.h>)
#import <UIKitExtension/UIKitExtension.h>
#endif

#else // no cocoapods, so enable everything

#import <UI7Kit/UI7Font.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7AlertView.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7ActionSheet.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7BarButtonItem.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7Button.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7NavigationBar.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7NavigationController.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7ProgressView.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7PickerView.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7SearchBar.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7SegmentedControl.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7Slider.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7Stepper.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7TabBar.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7TabBarItem.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7TabBarController.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7TableView.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7TextField.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7Toolbar.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7View.h>
#import <UI7Kit/UI7ViewController.h>
#import <UIKitExtension/UIKitExtension.h>

#endif // ifdef COCOAPODS
```

Thanks to @trojanfoe and @Fogmeister that tried to help me.